# pygame.mouse.get_pos()..... the x/y co-oridinates not updating

Tags: pygame, coordinates, python-idle

Trying to get a box to change color when the mouse goes over. The problem I'm having is that the mouse co-ordinates are not updating. So the program doesn't know that the mouse is over the specific location. How do I get it to keep updated the mouse co-ordinates?

```
def start_screen():
    game_display.blit(selection_screen,(0,0))
    #buttons

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print(mouse)
    if 200 + 100 > mouse[0] > 200 and 550 + 50 > mouse[1] > 550:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display,black,(200,550,100,50))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display,white,(200,550,100,50))
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display,white,(700,550,100,50))

    pygame.display.update()

start_screen()
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed it...

```
def start_screen():

    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            game_display.blit(selection_screen,(0,0))
            #buttons

            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if 200 + 100 > mouse[0] > 200 and 550 + 50 > mouse[1] > 550:
                pygame.draw.rect(game_display,black,(200,550,100,50))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(game_display,white,(200,550,100,50))

            pygame.draw.rect(game_display,white,(700,550,100,50))

            pygame.display.update()

start_screen()
```